# Ns2 wsn stop send receive and keep sense in a node?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, simulation, wireless, ns2

I have a wsn simulation and i want to know if it is possible to stop a node from sending and receiving while keep it sensing inorder to save energy? Is this senario possible?

I will reword my question. Is there any command that puts a node in sleep mode at a specific time? Then turn it on again after a while?

Comment: A sensor node **receives** data from a sensor. And **sends** the results to a destination. .... If you want no data : Set the nodes to idle / to sleep.

Comment: Yes but i want it to keep sensing data

Comment: Wouldn't save any energy : Whether you are using the default **send**, or you are **sending** the data to any kind of storage / any file, I guess the same energy will be used

Comment: I will reword my question. Is there any command that puts a node in sleep mode at a specific time? Then turn it on again after a while?

Comment: Did you read my answer here ? .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212410/how-to-set-a-node-to-sleep-in-ns2